# ASP.NET TreeNode SelectedNodeStyle having no effect

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have created a treeview to which I am dynamically adding values to. Everything seems to work fine - the selected event is being triggered and the treeview works perfectly. The only problem is that changing the selectednodestyle has no effect on the treeview.

Please help I have been researching this problem for quite a while now.

This is the html code for my treeview:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="treeViewProperties" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeViewPropertiesNodeSelected" Font-Bold="False" NodeIndent="10" ShowExpandCollapse="False">
      <HoverNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Goldenrod" />
      <NodeStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="White" HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
      <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
      <RootNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" />
      <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#FF33CC" ForeColor="#FF3399" Height="500px" />
    </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with Jquery.

I added a click event to the treeviewproperties nodes and added styling to the selected treenode.

here is the code:

```
    $(function () {
  $('.MainContent_treeViewProperties_3').click(function () {
    $(".MainContent_treeViewProperties_3").css('color', 'white');
    $(this).css('color', '#273F6F');
  });

  $('.MainContent_treeViewProperties_1').click(function () {
    $(".MainContent_treeViewProperties_1").css('text-decoration', '');
    if ($(this).is('.MainContent_treeViewProperties_3')) {
      // This is a root node do not change its color.
    }
    else {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    }

  });
});
```